# syntax error in python script

Tags: python, syntax-error

I wrote the following script, which generates a `SyntaxError`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Enter the filename: "
filename = raw_input("> ")
print "Here is your file %r: ", % filename

txt = open(filename)
print txt.read()
txt.close()
```

Here is the error:

```
  File "ex02.py", line 4
    print "Here is your file %r: ", % filename
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: thanks everyone. it was a stupid mistake. Just starting out with python :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble lies here:

```
print "Here is your file %r: ", % filename
                              ^
```

When `print` finds a comma, it uses that as an argument separator, as can be seen with:

```
>>> print 1,2
1 2
```

In that case, the next argument needs to be valid and the sequence `% filename` is *not.*

What you undoubtedly meant was:

```
print "Here is your file %r: " % filename
```

as per the following transcript:

```
>>> filename = "whatever"

>>> print "file is %r", % filename
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "file is %r", % filename
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> print "file is %r" % filename
file is 'whatever'
```

Comment: A comma at the end of a `print` statement changes the terminator from a newline to a space.

Comment: Of course, this changes in 3.x, where `print` becomes an actual function.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a comma there.

```
print ("Here is your file %r: " % filename),
```

Comment: @Abhranil: A comma at the end of a `print` statement changes the terminator from a newline to a space.

Comment: Oh good, I didn't know that! And what if I don't want even a space, do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Abhranil: You'd write directly to `sys.stdout`.

Answer (score 2):

The coma is not needed, try:

```
filename = raw_input("> ")
print "Here is your file %r: " % filename
```

Comment: Actually, the comma probably *is* needed. It just can't go *there*.